# Charting with Candlestick_OHLC

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, yahoo-finance

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import io
import datetime
import urllib
import urllib.request
%matplotlib notebook


urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;
              type=quote;range=1y/csv'

with urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit) as response:
    sourcePage = response.read().decode('utf-8')


df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(sourcePage), skiprows=18, header=None, sep=",", 
                 names=['date','closeP','highP','lowP','openP','volume'],
                 index_col= 0, parse_dates= True)

if 'volume' not in df:
        df['volume'] = np.zeros(len(df))

DATA = df[['openP', 'highP', 'lowP', 'closeP','volume']].values

f1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (1,0), rowspan=6, colspan=4, axisbg='#07000d')
candlestick_ohlc(f1, DATA, width=.6, colorup='#53c156', colordown='#ff1717')

f1.grid('on')
f1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(15))
f1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.09, bottom=.14, right=.94, top=.95, wspace=.20, hspace=0)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.show()
```

So here's the problem, when I try to plot the 'candlestick_ohlc' but it only plots the volume bar chart! (Why is this happening?) I'm thinking that maybe the problem has to do with my dates? I'm using iPython Notebook btw. My [source is from - Yahoo Finance](http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv). If you notice, I skipped the first 18 lines so that I can get straight to the actual data itself and it looks like:

```
20150302,569.7757,570.5834,557.2202,558.9953,2129600
20150303,572.0694,573.8146,564.9689,568.8881,1704700
20150304,571.8001,575.5299,566.4548,570.3043,1876800
20150305,573.7548,576.3277,571.8400,573.4456,1389600
20150306,566.1307,575.1011,565.2082,573.3060,1659100
20150309,567.2925,568.7086,561.9921,565.3079,1062100
```

date,close,high,low,open,volume

Any ideas? Would appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of @DSM,

```
DATA = df[['openP', 'highP', 'lowP', 'closeP','volume']]
DATA = DATA.reset_index()
DATA["date"]  = DATA["date"].apply(mdates.date2num)

f1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (1,0), rowspan=6, colspan=4, axisbg='#07000d')
candlestick_ohlc(f1, DATA.values, width=.6, colorup='#53c156', colordown='#ff1717')
```

fixed the problem! Credits to him.